# font-size not working when i try to get rid of space between inline block divs

Tags: html, css

want to get rid of the space between these divs so the images link up seamlessly.

I've asked a similar question, and i was brought to tutorials for no spacing between divs. 
I've tried no spacing between tags <>, no tags, font size zero, but i can't seem to get it working.

[image]

this is my code

html

```
<section style="font-size: 0px;">
                            <div  style="font-size: 0px;" class="items">
                                <div class="item item1"></div><div class="item item2"></div><div class="item item3"></div>
                            </section>
```

css

```
.items {
    display:flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    transform: scale(0.98);
    will-change: transform;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }

  .items.active {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    cursor: grabbing;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  .item {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('img/approach.png');
    min-height: 320px;
    min-width: 400px;
    margin: 2em 1em;
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      min-height: 200px;
      min-width: 200px;
    }
  }

 .item1 {
  background-image: url('../img/approachslice1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .item2 {
    background-image: url('../img/approachslice2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .item3 {
      background-image: url('../img/approachslice3.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }


}
```

codepen https://codepen.io/catbut_1/pen/YzXZRJz

Comment: You have a missing closing tag for your first `div` in your `section` (`items`) for starters and `font-size: 0px` is bad practice for whatever reason that's there as it shouldn't be necessary. Also the purpose for `position: relative`  and if you're going to use flex I'd suggest adding `flex-direction: row`. If you want to fix the basics and maybe move your example to the code editor so we can reproduce what you see it would be easier to help. Cheers!

Comment: You should add `background-size` for elements who have image as background

Comment: Is your goal to remove the space between the images? The title of your question relates to font-size not working, font-size will not affect the space between images.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS for the class `item` you have:

```
.item {

    ...

    margin: 2em 1em; // This creates the space between your images

    ...

  }
```

the `margin: 2em 1em` is creating the space between your images.

Try:

```
.item {
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('img/approach.png');
    min-height: 320px;
    min-width: 400px;
    margin: 2em 0em;
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      min-height: 200px;
      min-width: 200px;
    }
  }
```

I also agree with the comment from Chris W. up above - font size isn't relevant to removing space between your images, and is bad practice to set it to 0.